# ASP.NET MVC client validation with partial views and Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, validation

I'm using the client validation function of the MVC 2.0 framework
(with `Html.ValidationMessageFor()` and `Html.EnableClientValidation()`).

Everything is nice, when I use the validation in a simple form.

But when I get this form via jQuery Ajax

```
$.get('PathToMyForm', function(htmlResult) {
    $('selector').html(htmlResult);
});
```

client validation doesn't work. Why?

Comment: *How* does it not work?  The new fields aren't validated?  Nothing is validated?  Where is the validation code?  In the partial?  In the containing page?  A little more code and explanation would be helpful.

Comment: tvanfosson,
I have model with [Required] attribute.
In common scenario (without AJAX, just Html.RenderPartial) client validation works fine - if I type empty string in textbox and focus to another textbox, I get validation message.
But with AJAX - I don't get this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had problems with MVC validation and partial views too. I sorted it out by using jquery.validate.js instead of the build-in client-validation. You can try that out.

Comment: jQuery.validate can't see my model. I want to define validation rules in model classes.

Comment: You can do so. Check the ASP.NET MVC Futures http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742

Answer (score 7):

If you are using jquery.validate (particularly with MVC) and you are loading pages via AJAX, you need to make the following call after the page loads:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#validation"));
```

See more at my blog post: [Using Unobtrusive jQuery Validation with Forms Loaded via AJAX](http://www.jasoncavett.com/blog/using-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-with-forms-loaded-via-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe jQuery isn't evaluating the JavaScript code on the Ajax response?

Try using dataType property on the Ajax call,

```
$.get('PathToMyForm', {dataType 'html'}, function(htmlResult) {
    $('selector').html(htmlResult);
});
```

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

*dataType* Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)

The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will intelligently try to get the results, based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

Comment: Rafael Mueller, thank you for your answer, but it's doesn't help me.
I have included alert('scripts test') into my partial view - it works. But I still have a problems with validation.