# ASP MVC Grid with edit modal

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC 4 and Entity Framework and  [Grid.MVC](http://gridmvc.azurewebsites.net/) for datagrid.
I have tried to implement a modal dialog to edit records using bootstrap. 
When i click edit, modal window does not appear.

I follow the instruction how to create modal here: 
[Popup dialog for editing record using Grid.MVC in a ASP.NET MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594915/popup-dialog-for-editing-record-using-grid-mvc-in-a-asp-net-mvc3)

**here is my code**

[YOU CAN DOWNLOAD MY SAMPLE PROJECT HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/0hh98ytpo85nstc/ASP+MVC+CrudModalTest.rar)

**HomeController**

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult HR201()
    {
        DCHREmployee dchremp = new DCHREmployee();
        List<HREmployee> hrempList = new List<HREmployee>();
        foreach (HREmployee hremp_ in dchremp.GetHREmployee(""))
        {
            hrempList.Add(hremp_);
        }

        return View(hrempList);
    }



   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(String EmpID)
    {
        DCHREmployee dchremp = new DCHREmployee();
        List<HREmployee> hrempList = new List<HREmployee>();
        foreach (HREmployee hremp_ in dchremp.GetHREmployee(EmpID))
        {
            hrempList.Add(hremp_);
        }
      return View(hrempList[0]);
    }


}
```

**HR201 cshtml view**

```html
@model IEnumerable<TAObjectModel.HREmployee>
@using GridMvc.Html
@using TAObjectModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HR201";
}




<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")"></script>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        @helper RenderDeleteForm(HREmployee hremp)
{
        <form method="POST" action="@Url.Action("Delete", "HR201", new { EmpID = hremp.EmpID })">
            <button type="submit" class="modal-link" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete employee: @hremp.LastNm?');">
                Delete
            </button>
        </form>
}



        <h2>HR201</h2>

        <div class="pull-left">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                <button type="submit" class="modal-link">MODAL</button>
            }
        </div>

        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.EmpID).Titled("EmpID").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.FirstNm).Titled("First Name");
                        //columns.Add(c => c.MiddleNm).Titled("Middle Name");
                        //columns.Add(c => c.LastNm).Titled("Lastn Name");
                        columns.Add(c => c.BirthDt).Titled("BirthDay").Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}").Filterable(true);  
                        columns.Add().Titled("Action")
                            .Sanitized(false)
                            .Encoded(false)
                            .RenderValueAs(d => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit",  new { EmpID = d.EmpID }, new { @class = "modal-link" }));
                        columns.Add().Titled("Action2")

                            .Sanitized(false)
                            .Encoded(false)
                            .RenderValueAs(c => RenderDeleteForm(c));



                    }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)



        @Html.ActionLink("Click to Add Customer", "Edit",new{EmpID = "E9770003"}, new { @class = "modal-link" })
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Loading…</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        //this script reset modal each time when you click on the link:
        $(function () {
            $(".modal-link").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#myModal').removeData("modal");
                $('#myModal').modal({ remote: $(this).attr("href") });
            });
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT VIEW**

```html
<div class="container">



    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>HREmployee</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpID)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpID)
            </div>


            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstNm)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstNm)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstNm)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastNm)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastNm)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastNm)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleNm)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleNm)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleNm)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SenseID)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SenseID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SenseID)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NickNm)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NickNm)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NickNm)
            </div>


            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDt)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDt)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDt)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    </div>
```

**

Comment: try add your script  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")"></script> before any other scripts.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: I tried to move the script but it didn't work. Thanks :)

Comment: @Zaphod What do you mean error in console? sorry im just a newbie in ASP MVC. thanks.

Comment: Guys I uploaded a sample project so you can check, you can download here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/0hh98ytpo85nstc/ASP+MVC+CrudModalTest.rar