# How to Edit Grid.MVC using a pop-up modal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to move beyond a simple display of items in a table and would like to have a MVC grid that has edit/delete functionality. After a bunch of searching I can't seem to find a fairly clear article on how to do this. Most of the stuff that comes up is for expensive 3rd party controls like Telerik or DevExpress. I'm not able to purchase these controls.

I did find Grid.Mvc and it seems to be a highly recommended control. I've got the basics of it working but like mentioned earlier I need to start to implement a edit (to a modal) and confirming delete option.

It looks like what this user is doing is similar to what I'm looking to do. However it's really a question post and not a how to with some basic info.
[Popup dialog for editing record using Grid.MVC in a ASP.NET MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594915/popup-dialog-for-editing-record-using-grid-mvc-in-a-asp-net-mvc3)

I also can't really find anything about Edit/Delete on the Grid.Mvc documents section.

Does anyone have any suggestions on an article or video on how to work with MVC grids? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the documentation for MVC.Grid from here http://gridmvc.azurewebsites.net/

From the documentation, there is no Edit or Delete feature that is part of the Grid.  You can add an ActionLink that routes to a Action Method that will take care of the Edit and Delete functionality (as in the post you linked to in your question)

Comment: The link is broken.